# Change SQL mode from Single User to Multi-User for few or all bases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have **multiple** databases to change mode from `Single-User` to `Multi-User`.
I can use this to change one database.

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE CDN_Ceramika
SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

Is it possible to change mode for few bases or any query, when mode will be change for Multi-User just when a mode is Single-User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **undocumented** system procedure `sp_msforeachdb`:

```
USE master;

EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''model'') BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE ? SET MULTI_USER;
END;';
```

Comment: Need I change anythink in this code? I'm newbie in SQL. When I execute your code, I have long error. Example below:

`Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'master'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'master'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'master'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'master'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'tempdb'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
`

Comment: I'd missed the quotes around the first `?`, @BElluu. Try now.

Comment: I have this error now.
`Msg 5058, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Option 'MULTI_USER' cannot be set in database 'master'.
Msg 5058, Level 16, State 4, Line 2
Option 'MULTI_USER' cannot be set in database 'tempdb'.`

Comment: Typo of `tempdb` but no idea why you're getting the error about `master`. did it change the other databases though? (It should have done, if it didn't, then something else is underlying here that you haven't made us aware of)

Comment: @BElluu if you are a newbie ... how did the databases end up in single-user mode? Was there a problem? A maintenance script gone awry? Instead of trying scripts at random, inspect them first. Perhaps instead of using  `sp_MSforeachdb '` you should generate the `ALTER DATABASE` script for each database (eg by reading sys.databases) and inspect it before executing it

Answer (score 4):

If you are new to database management I'd advise *against* using `sys.sp_MSforeachdb`. Despite being undocumented it's a *very* popular function among DBAs that know and quadruple-check what they're doing. [This article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) explains some of its pitfalls.

It's generally safer to generate the command strings you want to execute with SQL, inspect them, fix any problems and execute the resulting script. Probably inside a transaction if appropriate.

As the article shows `sp_MSforeachdb` itself queries the `sys.databases` table. You can do the same, eg with :

```
select 'ALTER DATABASE [' + name + '] SET MULTI_USER;'
from sys.databases
where name not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb')
```

To generate `ALTER DATABASE` for all the databases you want, whose names match the `WHERE` clause. You could also write :

```
select 'ALTER DATABASE [' + name + '] SET MULTI_USER;'
from sys.databases
where name not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb')
and [user_access_desc] != 'MULTI_USER'
```

to exclude databases that are already in multi-user mode

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the database you wish to change, then click on Properties.

Click on Options and scroll down to the bottom, then set it as can be seen below:

[image]

Click OK and it will be set.

Comment: poster clearly states they want to automate across all databases!

Comment: Why the down mark? The question was asked by a newbie to SQL which the user admitted. So I gave him a simple answer, without using a script.

Comment: I suspect due to the reason Mitch gave. If you have a lot of databases, this would be tedious at best.

Comment: @Birel besides the OP *already* uses the T-SQL `ALTER DATABASE` command produced by that dialog box.